# Need to have testing server work with https: but don't have an SSL

Tags: apache, https

I'm working on an online store. I have it setup on my testing server. I'm having a problem where when it goes to the checkout functions it wants to start calling https pages. I don't have an SSL certificate for this server. Is there something I can do with Apache to get this to work? Mod_Rewrite perhaps? I've played a little with rewrites but haven't had any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much better if you could add SSL support with open_ssl and create your own self-signed certificate. self-signed certs are free to create.

Here is an example of instructions: http://www.flatmtn.com/article/setting-ssl-certificates-apache

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel comfortable with `openssl` you might also use [SimpleCA](http://www.vpnc.org/SimpleCA/) or [OpenCA](http://www.openca.org/projects/openca/) to create self-signed certificates. These are simple GUI programs that act as a Certificate Authority.